# stretch area outside figure - matlab

Tags: matlab

```
figure

h = axes('Position',[0 0 1 1]);
axes('Position',[.25 .1 .7 .8])

plot(rand(5, 1))

set(gcf,'CurrentAxes',h)
text(.02,.4,'text text text text text')
```

How can I left-stretch the outer space where I put the text so that it doesn't overlap with the axis numbers?

Comment: You need to change the axes position for that. Why are you creating _two_ axes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @CrisLuengo suggested, simply

```
figure('Color','w')
h = axes('Position',[0.45 0.1 0.5 0.85]);
plot(rand(5, 1))
text(-2,.4,'text text text text text')
```

will give you

[image]

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes, that's better. Just need to mention that the text is now in plot coordinates (e.g., negative in this case, rather than the [0,1] figure coordinates).